# Apply function Pandas ?? Implementation

Tags: python, pandas, apply, implementation

I made some function like this: `data['Age'] = data[['Age',School]].apply(age_implementation, axis = 1)` by doing so I want to full NaN values in "Age" column based on School of child and this is the definitione of my "age_implementation" function. 
Nevertheless when I try to apply function using code above nothing changes, how can I apply this function ?

Function:

```
def age_implementation(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    School= cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if School== 1:
            return 10
        elif School== 2:
            return 15
        elif School== 3:
            return 20
        else:
            return Age
```

Data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame("School":{1,2,3,1,2,2}, "Age":{NaN, NaN, 20, NaN, NaN, 15})
```

Comment: 1. We don't have your data 2. we don't have your code (`age_implementation`) 3. we can't see the output or error messages. Can you please fix these issues so someone can answer your question?

Comment: could you now help me ?

Comment: Yeah, you are assigning Age and School incorrectly. Hint: What is the type of `cols` inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

With how your doing it, i would implement it this way:

```
def age_implementation(cols):
    Age = cols.Age
    School= cols.School

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if School== 1:
            return 10
        elif School== 2:
            return 15
        elif School== 3:
            return 20
    else:
         return Age

data['Age'] = data.apply(age_implementation, axis = 1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   School  Age
0       1   10
1       2   15
2       3   20
3       1   10
4       2   15
5       2   15
```

Comment: I think keeping apply is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), this is faster:

```
data['Age']=data['Age'].fillna(data['School'].map({1:10,2:15,3:20}))
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
   School   Age
0       1  10.0
1       2  15.0
2       3  20.0
3       1  10.0
4       2  15.0
5       2  15.0
```

Comment: great it works! howevew why apply does not work in this case ?

Comment: For their question it seems like `df['School'].add(1).mul(5)` would also work.

Comment: You need :     `Age = cols[1]
    School= cols[0]`.
but really if the function is that simple it is not necessary to use `apply`.
if the logic is linear then you can use what it proposes @cs95

Comment: Series.map is faster